# Docusign api persisting data through multiple envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

Weird issue here. So I have a document that gets prepopulated with data from a crm. The crm has a lead object, which is what this is centered around. The lead can have companies on them as well as contacts. I take the lead id and query the crm for the associated objects. The response looks like this:

```
{
    "result": {
        "id": 1032,
        "entityType": "Leads",
        "primaryAccount": {
            "id": 10
        },
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": 72
            }
        ],
        
    }
}
```

If there is an account(which is actually company), I query that and get the data to prefill fields in docusign when the envelope is created from my code. If there are none, I pass nothing over, obviously.

Heres the problem.

If I send a document to a lead that prepopulates the company data and fill out the form, come back to my crm and remove the company, and resend the document, the company name still exists from the previous document. ONLY the company name. This company exists no where in our system and is not getting populated from our system. I have checked the envelope id and they are completely different envelope ids. I have checked our system for this data and it doesn't exist. I am at a complete loss as to why this is happening. Has anyone experienced this issue? I'd love to understand why this is happening. Thanks community!

Answer (score 1):

This was dumb and attributed to a lack of knowledge of docusign on my part. The field in question is Company field. It populates automatically from your profile in docusign, no matter if you pass a value in or not. Hopefully this helps someone else out and saves people some time.

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-field-types